# Como verificar dia da semana sendo 1,3,5

Tags: php, mysql

Galera,

Tenho um campo em minha tabela que guardo o dia do mês, exemplo

Mas nesse mesmo campo estou gravando a informação assim:
1,2,3,5,22

Hoje é dia 22 DAY( NOW( ) ) = 22

Veja que no meu campo o dia está `1,3,5` como hoje é 22 deveria trazer o registro.

Como posso verificar meu campo no mysql? Split? Se sim como posso usar?

Answer (score 4):

Use o `like`

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE campo LIKE "%5%"
```

Comment: Me desculpe, só dei o exemplo do dia da SEMANA, mas preciso do dia do  MÊS também. Então o like não resolve.

Comment: Então sua pergunta está muito confusa. Pq do jeito que está, o like funcionaria. Explique melhor.